# Unable to print Variable which has calling with random alphanumeric strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, random

I want to assign variable A and B with random string from below function. As I want to use it elsewhere in the program it to feed for password and confirm password while automating. when I run this print A or print B, it prints none. how to print what is generated.

```
import random
import string

# get random string password with letters, digits, and symbols
def get_random_password_string(length):
    password_characters = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation
    password = ''.join(random.choice(password_characters) for i in range(length))
    print("Random string password is:", password)

A=get_random_password_string(10)
B=get_random_password_string(10)
print(A)
print(B)
```

Comment: get_random_password_string() isn't returning anything..

Comment: Your function should `return password`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `return` keyword. By using it you are able to assign the output of a function to a variable and then print it.

```
def get_random_password_string(length):
    password_characters = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation
    password = ''.join(random.choice(password_characters) for i in range(length))
    return "Random string password is:", password

A=get_random_password_string(10)
B=get_random_password_string(10)
print(A)
print(B)
```

Comment: Thank you @Aleksander for addressing, I added return(password) instead of return "Random string password is:", password. now, it's printing values of A & B. Thank you Again.